# Unable to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 (boot-repair corrupts the installation)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've been struggling with installing Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop (I believe it's Asus N56VZ). I'm running on pre-installed Windows 8 and even though I'm able to install Ubuntu (13.04) and boot it by setting it as the primary boot option from BIOS, I'm unable to perform a clean dual boot (the Windows dual boot screen doesn't show up, instead it just boots to Windows if boot manager is set as the primary boot option).

I've tried:

1. EasyBCD, no luck with it. I get a screen asking for Windows installation CD with this option.
2. Boot-repair. I used ubuntu boot repair from a live session. It corrupted the booting totally; I got booted to grub resque ("something too small" (not sure about the exact message) when booting Windows, unknown filesystem when booting the Ubuntu). I had to change the boot to my LiveUSB and uninstall Ubuntu with Os-Uninstall in order to get Win8 operational.

Here's the paste that Boot-Repair created:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5926812/

Answer (score 0):

Your sda8 looks like a left over encrypted swap from your previous install. You should not need EasyBCD with UEFI as each system installs its boot files into the efi partition as a separate folder and you can boot every install directly from UEFI if necessary.

If you run Boot-Repair more than once it renames the Windows boot file. Some systems have (incorrectly) modified UEFI to only boot bootmfgw.efi or only boot Windows. The work around is to back up the Windows file and rename shim to have that name as shim has the Microsoft signing key. But you only need the rename if you can only boot Windows from UEFI menu.

If you can (or after other fixes can) boot Ubuntu, you can run unrename the Windows file.
Boot-Repair - Updated Jan 1, 2013 to not rename first time, but rename if first time Windows does not boot. Post 706 and 711

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482&page=71
 Boot-Repair copied /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (in case the BIOS is hard-coded to boot into /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or secure boot signed GRUB file shimx64.efi.

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair. 
A user disabled secure boot, and unchecked it in boot-repair. It now bypasses Grub and goes straight in to Windows as UEFI default.

You do show grub installed and if you boot ubuntu entry from UEFI menu with secure boot off, does it boot? You may get grub menu, but also need boot parameters if you have video issues. If you can only boot with secure boot on, then you need to use Boot-Repair to add the secure boot versions of the kernel which you have not installed.

Grub2 has a bug in os-prober and does not create correct chain load entries. It creates the old BIOS entries that will not work with UEFI. Boot-Repair normally adds a 25_custom with correct entries, but did not (yet?) create those for you. You can manually add entries to 40_custom as per bug report.

grub2's os-prober creates wrong style (BIOS) chain boot entry

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383

type of entry from Boot-Repair that should work.
menuentry "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" {
menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {

Type of entry that does not work:
'Windows ...) (on /dev/sdXY)'

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. Seems so that the option youre speaking of (restore efi backups) has been removed from Boot-repair. Also I would like to point out that I am able to boot ubuntu if I change it so from BIOS. However, boot-repair freezes on the installed version of ubuntu (couldnt find something, cant remember what exactly). Oh, and I cant load Windows from the screen that appears when I boot Ubuntu even though I have options to (I get an error).